# WindowLeaked issue

Tags: java, android

I am having a big problem with WindowLeaked:

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity CrearGrupo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3702bf39 V.E..... R....... 0,0-960,883} that was originally added here
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                             at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                             at es.uva.tel.gco.CrearGrupo$2.onClick(CrearGrupo.java:175)
                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here the code:

```
            final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(activity, R.style.dialog);
            tituloDialogo=res.getString(R.string.crearGrupoDiálogo);
            dialog2.setTitle(tituloDialogo +" "+listaAsignaturas.get(pos));
            dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.prefijo_grupo);
if (control == 0){
                        //listNotebooks(pos);
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MostrarCrearGrupos.class);
                        intent.putExtra("asignatura",listaAsignaturas.get(pos));
                        intent.putExtra("prefijo",prefGrupo.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("nombreLibreta",notebookName);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
            });
            dialog2.show();
```

Dialog is a normal window with 2 inputs that let you enter one name and 1 prefix but when I try to show another dialog the app crash. 
I already look for a solution and try to solve it with:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dialog2 != null) {
        dialog2.dismiss();
        dialog2 = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (dialog2 != null) {
        dialog2.dismiss();
        dialog2 = null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if (dialog2 != null) {
        dialog2.dismiss();
        dialog2 = null;
    }

}
```

But it doesnt work. Any ideas.

Thx for your answers. :)

Comment: remove dialog2 = null; from all 3 methods

Comment: and you creating new dialog2 objects every time:  final Dialog dialog2  change it with making global dialog object

Comment: @Aquo169 Before calling the Intent you have to dismiss the dialog.if (control == 0){ dialog2.dismiss() 
// All your intent code}

Comment: This is a warning that your dialog  was not dismissed before starting a new intent . Use `dialog2.dismiss();` and then perform redirection operations !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case, you are try to call dialog2.show() after starting the new activity. Remove that and your code will work.

Here is the main reason why Leaked windows error occurs:

We know that every Activity Android has an WindowManager window manager, likewise, is built on top of a Activity dialog box, PopupWindow also has the corresponding WindowManager window manager. Because the dialog box, the PopupWindown from the Activity and should not exist alone, So when a Dialog or a PopupWindow is displayed when we go to finish () carrying the Dialog (or PopupWindow) Activity, Window Leaked exception will be thrown., Because the Dialog (or PopupWindow) WindowManager have who can not affiliated., So the window manager it has leaked.

Android.view.WindowLeaked usually occur in the display of Activity and Dialog.

Create Activity in a Dialog, and if you turn off Dialog first and then close the Activity is normal, if you shut down the Activity first and then close the Dialog will error the error android.view.WindowLeaked. 
Analysis the reason is: Dialog is created based on Activity: new ProgressDialog (this); this is Activity. Activtity finish first, then Dialog will have no attachment, so will report android.view.WindowLeaked.

Comment: I try to set dialog2.show() befeore the if(control==0) and set dialog2.dissmis between if and inten but I still have the windowleak :(

Comment: Why you are opening the dialog and intent at same time. You should put that dialog.show() in else part. Like:  if(control == 0){ startActivity();} else{ dialog.show();}

Comment: Im trying to do a dialog to get some necessary info. When the user introduce it and press continue, new window will get and process this info.

Comment: I think I got it. Just move show over if and introduce a dismiss in the condition. Thx for the answers :)